# How to add jar to classpath in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

after downloading a .jar file i need to include it in my classpath as the creator says in this page:
https://arnaudnouard.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/undecorator-add-a-better-look-to-your-javafx-stages-part-i/

But how can i do it in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: After looking on the web(where i found no fix) i've found a solution myself.
1. Go on the import statement that you're trying to use.
2. Click on the error symbol on the left side of the line.
3. Click "Add 'requires libraryname' directive to module-info.java"
That's it!

Answer (score 2):

You may add it as module dependency: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html

Comment: When i go to:
File > Project Structure > Modules > Dependencies
the library is there but when i perform import in the main class it doesn't work, neither code completion finds the library...

Comment: I am facing the same problem in trying to include poi-5.2.5, dependencies seem to by ok but import fails