# How to add commons-math3-3.1.1.jar to intellij classpath

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, grails, apache-commons

because I got no answer on thread
[How to add jar to classpath in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71456453/how-to-add-jar-to-classpath-in-intellij)
and I'm not the only one facing the problem I repeat this question in a new thread.
I tried the file/Project Structure/Dependencies/jars feature. though everything seems ok after doing so I cannot import commons-math

Peter

Comment: Where did you get the library jar? Is it valid? Does it contain packages and .class files? Can you show how you added it to the module dependencies and what specific imports do not work for you? It would help if you could share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on GitHub.

Comment: I wanted to upload the screenshots to document what I did and what import does not work, but rhe system always blames 'body missing' What the heck is a body in the context of uploading pictures, I give up.

Comment: You can share everything on GitHub and provide a link here.

Comment: that's what I'm going to do next

Comment: I now shared a completley simplified project on GitHub. It is a grails project generated from scratch with just a directory lib added that contains 'commons-math3-3.6.1.jar. The jar is referenced from ProjectStructure as an external library. Additionally I added just 1 controller MathImportController.groovy containing the import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.*. But  it is grayed and therefore NormalDistribution as part of .....distribution is not accessible. Here is the Link to Github https://github.com/pstrotmann/commonMath

Comment: Why not add it to the deps? And even if that jar is nowhere published,
adding it via gradle means is way more favourable.  If the only place,
you can build your project is your IDE, then you are in a bad place.

Comment: That's exactly what I did and described in my answer. Have a look to my updated repository: build.gradle file, dependencies section.

Comment: implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar']) should be commented out , because grails blames a war generation duplicate lib. the compileOnly Entry will do.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

create a dir 'lib',

store the jar in it

right click on the jar and make it an external library

and last but not least enter two lines in build.gradle:

compileOnly fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])

there is nothing to enter in project structure

but don't forget to refresh the dependencies via grails command

rebuild the project,

close it and open it again

peter